# Login form giving success even on wrong username/password

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a login form like:

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?> 

<div id="loginpart">  
<?php  
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))  
{  
 ?>   
 You are logged in as <b><?=$_SESSION['Username'];?> </b>. | <a     href="logout.php">LogOut</a>
 <?php  
}  
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))  
{  
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));  
$checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$username."' AND user_password = '".$password."'");  
if($checklogin)  
{  
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($checklogin);
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username; 
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;  
    echo "<p>Success: We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";  
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;index.php' />";
    //header('Location:index.php');  
}  
else  
{  
    echo "<p>Error: Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a     href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";  
}  
}  
else  
{  
?>    
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">   
    Username:<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />  
| <a href="register.php">Register</a>  
</form>  
<?php  
}  
?>  
</div>
```

It checks first if user is logged in or no. If no, then log it in.
Included base.php calling database:

```
<?php  
session_start();  
$dbhost = "localhost"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ  
$dbname = "login"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this  project  
$dbuser = "root"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your     database  
$dbpass = ""; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database  
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
?>
```

The error is in 2nd bracket where it is checking username and password.

Database table is:

```
create table user(
user_ID smallint unsigned auto_increment,
username varchar(30),
user_password varchar(16),
user_fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
user_lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
user_contact varchar(14),
user_email varchar(30),
user_street varchar(20),
user_city varchar(20),
constraint pk_user primary key (user_ID)
) engine innodb;
```

The issue is that even if I enter a wrong username or password. It logs me in. Someone please help where I am wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a password for ur database as `""`

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking if a row is being returned.

`if($checklogin)` will always evaluate to true, even when the result set is empty (because the password was wrong or the user was not found).

You need to replace this if clause with one which will check for a non-empty result set, e.g.:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) > 0)
```

As a side note: you may also want to pick more expressional variable names, e.g. `$checklogin_result` and `$checklogin_row` so that you won't loose sight if your project gets really big one day ;)

Comment: An MD5 hash consumes 32 hexadecimal digits, please try to convert your user_password column accordingly. Currently, you only store the first 16 digits of it and compare this to the freshly calculated hash with the correct length of 32 digits, which will of course always fail.

Answer (score 3):

It's returning success probably because there is no syntax error and your query executed successfully. But that does not mean rows were returned. Empty rows needs to be checked

```
if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) > 0)  
{  
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($checklogin);
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username; 
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;  
    echo "<p>Success: We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";  
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;index.php' />";
    //header('Location:index.php');  
}  
else  
{  
    echo "<p>Error: Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a     href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";  
}
```